# Apache tika parsing is very slow for file size greater than 2-3MB

Tags: apache-tika

We are using apache tika 1.24 version for detecting and extracting various files data, this code is working for smaller size files but its failing to extract data for 2-3mb files. Did any one faced this issue with this library for larger size files?

```
private void validate(stream: TikaInputStream) {

            val parser   = new AutoDetectParser();
            val handler  = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
            val metaData = new Metadata();
            val context = new ParseContext();
            val pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
            pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
            pdfConfig.setExtractUniqueInlineImagesOnly(true);
            context.set(classOf[PDFParserConfig], pdfConfig);
            context.set(classOf[EmbeddedDocumentExtractor], new EmbeddedImageFinder(t));
            parser.parse(stream, handler, metaData, context);
              val content       = handler.toString();

  }
```

Comment: What is your Java heap memory size?

Comment: We are using the following jvm memory arguments  -                                     
  Xms705M -Xmx705M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=123M -Xss512K -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64M

Comment: For a very heavily compressed file, that won't be enough. Should be fine for most, but not all files of that size. Try increasing `-Xmx` size?

Comment: I tried with -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M -Xss2048K -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M still i see the same issue